# Retrieving company name from HMService and/or HMAccessory object instance

Tags: accessory, ios8.3, homekit

I am using **Home Kit Accessory simulator** and I'd like to retrieve the company name of an accessory from an instance of **HMService**. However, when I add a breakpoint I cannot see any field related to the company name (I searched in both HMService and **HMAccessory**).

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

You can get name of **Manufacturer** from **HMServiceTypeAccessoryInformation service**, Service contains characteristic array in this there is **HMCharacteristicTypeManufacturer** characteristic.

You can use this to display name of company.

```
- (HMCharacteristic *)characteristicForAccessory:(HMAccessory *)accessoryValue{

HMAccessory *thisAccessory = accessoryValue;
HMService *service;
for (HMService *thisService in thisAccessory.services) {
    if([thisService.serviceType isEqualToString:HMServiceTypeAccessoryInformation])    {
        service = thisService;
    }
}
HMCharacteristic *characteristic;
if (service)   {
    for (HMCharacteristic *charact in service.characteristics) {
        if ([charact.characteristicType isEqualToString:HMCharacteristicTypeManufacturer]) {
            characteristic = charact;
        }
    }
}

return characteristic;
```

}

Use Characteristic object's value property to get name of manufacturer.

Like characteristic.value

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Raeid Saqur's [RSHomeKit](https://github.com/raeidsaqur/rshomekit/blob/master/RSHomeKit/HomeKitUtility.h) framework:

You can get accessory by calling service.accessory. Then use:

```
+ (NSString *)getManufacturerNameForHMAccessory:(HMAccessory *)accessory;

+ (NSString *)getManufacturerNameForHMAccessory:(HMAccessory *)accessory {
    if (!accessory) {
        return nil;
    }
    HMCharacteristic *manufacturer = [HomeKitUtility getCharacteristicWithUUID:HMCharacteristicTypeManufacturer forAccessory:accessory];

if (manufacturer && manufacturer.value) {
    return (NSString *)manufacturer.value;
}
    return nil;
}
```